# Does Objectify support Joda-Time Interval class?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jodatime, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

We use Objectify 5 to access Google Cloud Datastore. We have an entity with a property of type `Interval` from Joda-Time library. When we try to save such an entity, we get the error below. It seems that Objectify has problem with `Chronology` and its subclasses.

```
com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException: Error saving MyEntity(null): Class 'class org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology' is not a registered @Subclass
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.save(EntityMetadata.java:95)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.WriteEngine.save(WriteEngine.java:75)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.SaverImpl.entities(SaverImpl.java:60)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.SaverImpl.entity(SaverImpl.java:35)
...
```

We registered Joda-Time translators in Objectify along with our entities as follows.

```
...

// Joda-Time translators
JodaTimeTranslators.add(ObjectifyService.factory());

// persistent entities
ObjectifyService.register(MyEntity.class);

...
```

When we use `DateTime` instead of `Interval`, it works perfectly OK. Did we miss something? Does Objectify support Joda-Time `Interval` out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/translate/opt/joda/JodaTimeTranslators.java?r=2d48a85eae3a679c0dc0d01631de99f3b4775b29), obviously not. Supported types are:

```
DateTimeZone
LocalDate
LocalDateTime
DateTime (via ReadableInstant)
```

Maybe you can learn from the source code and write your own translator/adapter, see for example the source code of [LocalDateTranslatorFactory](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/translate/opt/joda/LocalDateTranslatorFactory.java?r=2d48a85eae3a679c0dc0d01631de99f3b4775b29) It does not seem to be so difficult. But you have probably to register your own adapter anyway.

Comment: Yes, I checked the source code, I just wanted to be sure that I did not miss anything.